# waitForReadyRead returns empty string - Why isnt it blocking?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I currenlty have a blocking model and the code where my client receives data is as follows

```
QByteArray tick_stream;
clntSocket->waitForReadyRead(-1);
tick_stream = clntSocket->read(800);
```

Now I believe `clntSocket->waitForReadyRead();` should only unblock when there is data to be read from the socket however it seems that it unblocks by itself and tick_stream is empty any suggetsions on what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for errors, because it can happen that the method will return immediately on error.

From [QtDoc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead):

> bool QIODevice::waitForReadyRead(int msecs) [virtual]
>
> Blocks until new data is available for reading and the readyRead() signal has been emitted, or until msecs milliseconds have passed. If msecs is -1, this function will not time out.
>
> Returns true if new data is available for reading; otherwise returns false (if the operation timed out or if an error occurred).

Comment: Yes it is returning false. How do i detect the type of error or extract the error message ?

Comment: Please consult the documentation, I am not very used to Qt. There definitly is something.

Comment: What actually hapened?